# Django Rest Framework - How to create a custom serializer for GoogleSheets

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, google-sheets-api

I have some data on a Google Sheet that I'd like to serialize. I've been working on using a Django server to create a REST API that makes it easy for other apps to use.

My use case is that we have several different Google Sheet Documents with data about devices we want to serialize. Python has a lot of neat libraries, like [SheetFu](https://github.com/socialpoint-labs/sheetfu), that basically do what we want, so I'd like to integrate that functionality with a REST API to do things like search, filter, etc.

I did find a Django app, [django-gsheets](https://github.com/MeanPug/django-gsheets/tree/master/gsheets) that combined with the Django-Rest-Framework does almost what I want, but it looks like models are fixed to a single Google Sheet Document - I need to be able to work with, and add multiple documents.

I can use SheetFu to write a serializer, but I'm not sure how to integrate that with Django, and it's REST framework - can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Thanks!